# Unable to acccess nginx pod across nodes using ClusterIP

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

I have created nginx deployment and nginx service(ClusterIP) to access nginx pod. But not able to access pod through cluster IP across nodes other than node where pod is scheduled.

I tried looking for IPtable too. But do not DNAT entry over there.

```
root@kdm-master-1:~# k get all -A -o wide |grep nginx
default       pod/nginx-6db489d4b7-pfkm9                 1/1     Running   0          3h16m   10.244.1.3   kdm-worker-1   <none>           <none>

default       service/nginx        ClusterIP   10.102.239.131   <none>        80/TCP                   3h20m   run=nginx

default       deployment.apps/nginx     1/1     1            1           3h32m   nginx        nginx                      run=nginx

default       replicaset.apps/nginx-6db489d4b7     1         1         1       3h32m   nginx        nginx                      pod-template-hash=6db489d4b7,run=nginx
```

IP table:

```
root@kdm-master-1:~# iptables -L -t nat|grep nginx
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  -- !10.244.0.0/16        10.102.239.131       /* default/nginx:80-80 cluster IP */ tcp dpt:http

KUBE-SVC-OVTWZ4GROBJZO4C5  tcp  --  anywhere             10.102.239.131       /* default/nginx:80-80 cluster IP */ tcp dpt:http
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

Please advice how can I resolve it?

Comment: 1. How are you trying to access that pod? 2. Is there any error message?

Comment: curl 10.102.239.131 (This is successful on node where nginx pod is scheduled)
But if I use the same curl command from other nodes, it just freezes after pressing enter? Does it has something to do with flannel? Please advice?

Comment: Hi Mark, it worked like charm but a silly mistake I did.  Somehow I didn't uncomment the ip forwarding rule to 1 in system.conf file.  Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Consider posting it as an answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

`run sysctl --system`

This will resolve the issue and one will be able able to access the pod from any node.